# Accessible news ticker plugin

Tags: wordpress, accessibility, ticker, news-ticker

I'm looking for a Wordpress plugin which would show horizontally scrolling news (left to right), and should comply with the accessibility standards.

So it cannot use the "marquee" tag, and should allow a disabled user to stop and restart the scrolling effect.

Is there such a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the plugin "Smooth Slider" which has many customization options.
You can stop posts images from showing and then you get only the text scrolling.
Works for me.